# Limiting the number of JSON rows that returns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Let's say in the controller we have something like this:

```
@org = Org.includes(programs: :patient_counts]).find(params[:id])
respond_with(@org)
```

and now I pass this to JBuilder:

```
json.program @org.programs do |program|
  json.(program, :name)
  # more code to also return some info from patien_counts table too
end
```

So if I have like 200 programs and in a 1-1 relationship I have also 200 patient_counts then the JSON that gets returned will have 200 objects.  BUT in my case I only want a certain amount of them. For example I lets say patient_counts table has two fields called Salary and Bonus and I want to return 15 objects in the JSON, not all of those 200 objects..only 15 of them that have highest Salary+Bonus.

For logic and calculations like this scenario what should I do?

**EDIT: Info about Models:**

```
program.rb :
name:string
has_many: patient_conuts

patient_count.rb:
belongs_to: program
program_id  # from the program above
total_amount: integer
```

Comment: Can you update the question with your models

Comment: @AnkitG Thanks Sir for following, Ok I updated with model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you have the model return the dataset to you with the conditions that you are having so that you don't have to work on the JSON for filtering

Update:

```
class Program < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :patient_counts
 scope :salary_and_bonus, ->(salary,bonus) {where("salary >= :salary AND bonus >= :bonus ', {salary: salary, bonus: bonus}).limit(15)} 
end
end
```

eg

```
Program.includes(:patient_counts).salary_and_bonus(15,20) #15 and 20 are my assumed limits
```

Comment: because I don't enough knowledge of that!  Can you please explain more? My models are pretty empty, just a bunch of has_many, belongs_to for program and patient_count models.

Comment: Thanks for sample answer. What is it if I want to say "top 20" of salary field? (ie. Listing the top 20 people with highest salary)

Comment: if you want for just the salary thn modify the scope with just the salary condition and keep the limit to 20.  By default it will pick the top 20 from the table which satisfy your salary criteria.